# How to convert an url into a hyperlink with php urlencode()?

Tags: php, regex, url, hyperlink, hebrew

Trying to convert a plain URL text into a valid link.

The problem I have is that my link might contain ***both*** **English** (A-Z/a-z) and **Hebrew** (אבגדהוזחטיכךלמםנןסעפףצץקרשת) letters.

Using PHP's `urlencode()` function I was able to get the correct format for Hebrew, yet I cannot find the right way in which I convert it into a link.

My code so far (*does not work with Hebrew letters*):

```
$replyText = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $replyText);
```

An example for a URL I need to convert into a link:

> google.co.il%2F%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D_Hello.html

Will become:

> [google.co.il%2F%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D_Hello.html](http://google.co.il%2F%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D_Hello.html)

Comment: If you use the u modifier, `\w` is able to match hebrew letters too.

Comment: If you want to encode urls, use preg_replace_callback.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/wOoFNw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what I believe you have posted to represent the desired output, if this was my task, I think I would have a urlencoded `href` value in the `<a>` tag and human-readable link text.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iFVuY))

```
$replyText = "google.co.il%2F%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D_Hello.html";
echo '<a href="', str_replace('%2F','/',$replyText), '">', urldecode($replyText), '</a>';
```

Source Code Output:

```
<a href="google.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D_Hello.html">google.co.il/שלום_Hello.html</a>
```

Effective Output:

[google.co.il/שלום_Hello.html](http://google.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D_Hello.html)

Notice that when you mouseover the link, your browser's status bar will show the un-encoded url anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace `%2F` => `/`, so your link will be: `google.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D_Hello.html`

[link](http://google.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D_Hello.html)